# Read text value and change the strings value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code below. I want to change the H2 message `No results were found for this query: <em class="querytext">`to something like `"No results were found by hello world!` without hard coding as I have no control of the piece of text in an HTML file, is their any way I can do this via an if condition CSS or JS to read the string then change the message on load of the page? something like `if text == No results were found for this query:` display `"No results were found by hello world!`.

```
<div class="search-results">
    <h2>No results were found for this query: <em class="querytext"></em></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of control do you have? What is the context of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try DOM manipulation with JavaScript:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function updateResultText(text) {
            var resultTextEl = document.querySelector('.search-results > h2');
            if(resultTextEl) {
              resultTextEl.innerText = "No results were found by " + text;
            }
          }
    </script>
    <button onclick="updateResultText('hello world!')">Update Text</button>
   <div class="search-results">
     
    <h2>No results were found for this query: <em class="querytext"></em>
    </h2>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JS you need is below:

```js
function updateResultText(text) {
            var resultTextEl = document.querySelector('.search-results > h2');
            if(resultTextEl) {
              resultTextEl.innerText = "No results were found by " + text;
            }
          }
```

You would then make the call to `updateResultText` with whatever you want the text following 'by ' to consist of.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses vanilla JS to change all `h2` that are child of `.search-results` class:

```js
for (let h2 of document.querySelectorAll('.search-results > h2')) {
  if (h2.textContent.search('No results were found for this query') >= 0)
    h2.textContent = 'No results were found by hello world!';
}
```

```html
<div class="search-results">
  <h2>No results were found for this query: <em class="querytext"></em>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Please advise, not sure why its not changing the text

Comment: Can you share more about how it's failing? On what context are you working? Are your changes actually persisting? Maybe some cache isn't allowing you to see your updates. The code works, I tested in multiple machines and in multiple browsers and plz don't hurry to downvote.

Comment: The string only appears after an ajax call in your app.bundle script (after the loading spinner), that's why it's not working (the code runs before the result string is rendered). To fix you can add the answer code to the ajax callback or make it run repeatedly with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). And it definitely works, you can open the site, wait for the string to appear ad paste the code in the console panel (F12)

Answer (score 0):

At end of your page put the following script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var elem= document.querySelector('.search-results > h2');
            if(elem) {
             if(elem.innerText.indexOf("No results were found for this query")>=0)
                 elem.innerHtml="anything You want !!";
            }
          }
    </script>
```

then after that there should be `</body></html>` tags.

Comment: The `indexOf` method returns -1 when no results are found. Shouldn't you check if it's >= 0 (greater or equal)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Yes. Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @nAviD its not working it says expression expected near the if.

Comment: `document.querySelector` only returns one element. You cannot access it like an array or NodeList; you're essentially accessing the property '0' on the returned `HTMLElement` which is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

old JavaScript

```
var query = "" // Get the username from either the backend, URL, or any other way like simple login form to the local storage without backend

var newText = 'No results were found for this' + query ': <em class="querytext"></em></h2>'

var el = document.querySelector('.search-results h2').innerHTML = newText
```

ES5

```
const query = "" // Get the username from either the backend, URL, or any other way like simple login form to the local storage without backend

const newText = `No results were found for this ${query}: <em class="querytext"></em></h2>`

const el = document.querySelector('.search-results h2').innerHTML = newText
```